# NSMutableArray quick search????/

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray with the following objects:

```
  @interface MyViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    NSUInteger id;
    .....
  }
```

In some method I need quick search for the cell with predefined id. How the best to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use `- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate`.  See documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

```
int index = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    MyViewCell *cell = (MyViewCell *)obj;
    BOOL result = (cell.id == someValue);
    stop = &result;
    return result;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. And How I can get the found MyViewCell? As I understand it is only searching for the predefined id.

Comment: `[myArray objectAtIndex:index]`

Answer (score 1):

When I tried the code, I encountered a small problem. The next adjust code worked fine for me (***stop**):

```
int index = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    MyViewCell *cell = (MyViewCell *)obj;
    BOOL result = (cell.id == someValue);
    *stop = result;
    return result;
}];
```